# What does “in position time” normally mean in the aviation industry?

Tags: commercial-operations, flight-schedules

I’ve read route descriptions for a cargo company, and they have a line for “in position time”.

What does in position time correspond to as industry jargon? Does it mean holding short of the runway, ready to taxi, at the flight planning room, or something else?

Comment: What can you glean from the other times surrounding it?  i.e. are there lines for show, engine start, takeoff, etc?  And if so, where in the order does this one fit?  It seems like you might be able to narrow it down based on context.

Comment: @Michael Hall I suspect that it’s the time to begin the takeoff roll, but it can’t hurt to ask. Once I find out 100% I’ll just answer my own question if it doesn’t already receive a definitive answer.

Comment: But what do the other lines say?  Where does this fall in the timeline of events?  Please tell us what you do know to help us help you...  (for example, if it occurs sequentially after a line for taxiing then it obviously can't be for the crew to meet "at the flight planning room", right?!  Surely there are other lines besides this one?)